# C++ function with unsigned int parameter gets strange result where call it with negitive

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, I am confused with  C++'s behavior for the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
void hello(unsigned int x, unsigned int y){
    std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<y<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<x+y<<std::endl;
}

int main(){
    int a = -1;
    int b = 3;
    hello(a,b);
    return 1;
}
```

The x in the output is a very large integer:4294967295, I know that negative integer convert to unsigned will behave like this. But why x+y in the output is 2?

Comment: Integer overflow. I'd suggest reading up on two's complement arithmetic to really understand what's happening on the bit-level.

Comment: Work through the values on paper.  (Use 8-bit values instead of 32-bit values to make it easier.)  -1 is 11111111 in base 2.  3 is 0000011.  Add those and what do you get?

Comment: Why would you pass a signed value as a parameter when the formal argument is unsigned? Easy answer: don't.

Comment: @Yuushi: It's not about integer overflow; it's about the well-defined semantics of signed-to-unsigned conversion.

Comment: What would you expect to see, 4294967298?

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to the other answers, there is no undefined behavior here, and there is no overflow. Unsigned integers use modulo 2<sup>*n*</sup> arithmetic.

Section 4.7 paragraph 2 of the standard says "If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>*n*</sup> where *n* is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type)." This dictates that -1 is equal to the largest possible unsigned int (modulo 2<sup>*n*</sup>).

Section 3.9.1 paragraph 4 says "Unsigned integers, declared unsigned, shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2<sup>*n*</sup> where *n* is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer." To make it clear what this means, the footnote to this clause says "This implies that unsigned arithmetic does not overflow because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type."

In other words, converting -1 to 4294967295 is not just defined behavior, it is *required* behavior (assuming 32 bit integers). Similarly, adding 3 to that value and yielding 2 as a result is also required behavior. In this case, the value of *n* is irrelevant. The third value printed by `hello()` must be 2 or the implementation is not compliant with the standard.

Comment: @uncletall - In which way? What's unclear about "Unsigned integers use modulo 2^n arithmetic" ?

Comment: Nothing really, it just very formal... and I have no idea what "congruent" means..

Answer (score 0):

Because unsigned int's will overflow. In other words, a=-1 (signed) which is 1 value below the maximum value for unsigned int's, 4294967295.
Then you add 3, the int will overflow and start at 0, so -1+3 =2

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is no overflow; the result is specified by the semantics of signed-to-unsigned conversion (and by the value of `UINT_MAX` in the given implementation).

Comment: Maybe that is not what section 3.9.1 of the C++ laws call it, but it is what 99.99% of the C++ programmers would call it

Answer (score 0):

Passing negative number to unsigned int as parameter gives you an undefined behavior. The default int is a signed. It has a range of –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. Unsigned int range is from 0 to 4,294,967,295.

Comment: No, the value is converted and the behavior is well defined.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't so much having to do with C++ but with how computers represent signed and unsigned numbers.

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) is a good source on that. Basically, signed numbers are (usually) represented using two's complement, in which the most significant bit has a value of -2^n. In effect, what his means is that the positive numbers are represented the same in two's complement as they are in regular unsigned binary.

-1 is represented as all ones, which when interpreted as an unsigned integer will be the largest integer that can be represented (4294967295, when dealing with 32 bits).

One of the great things about using two complement to represent signed numbers is that you can perform addition and subtraction in the exact same way as with unsigned numbers and it will work out correctly, so long as the number does not exceed the bounds that can be represented. This isn't as easy with other forms such as signed-magnitude.

So, what this means is that because the result of -1 + 3 = 2, and because 2 is positive, it will be interpreted the same as if it were unsigned. Thus, it prints 2.

Comment: The behavior is defined by the C++ standard. It happens to be convenient for 2's-complement systems, but even on a 1's-complement or sign-and-magnitude system it would have to behave the same way.